# Sqlite database size compare with local db size

Tags: android, sqlite

I have got SDcard database file and app sqlite database how do i compare the size? when i run this code below, always crashing..

```
   private ContextWrapper context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + externalPath
            + FileName);

    File f = context.getDatabasePath(DB_PATH);
    long dbSize = f.length();

    if (dbSize <= myFile.length()) {

            //code here


    } else {



    }
```

appreciate your help…

```
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): Process:    in.wptrafficanalyzer.searchdialogdemo, PID: 1085
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity  ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.searchdialogdemo/in.wptrafficanalyzer.searchdialogdemo.Lite Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.searchdialogdemo.LiteActivity.onCreate(LiteActivity.java:65)
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 05-18 02:33:05.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post logcat where you are getting exception

Comment: What is line 65 of LiteActivity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: File f = context.getDatabasePath(DB_PATH);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `context` is null as you have not initialized it.

Since you're running in a method of an activity, there's no point really storing a `Context` as a member variable. Use `this` instead. Replace

```
context.getDatabasePath(DB_PATH);
```

with just

```
getDatabasePath(DB_PATH);
```